# ICEfaces configured for view, but h:head and h:body components are required

Tags: icefaces

i am trying to use icefaces 3, and configuring the rime theme as follows:

org.icefaces.ace.theme
        rime

but i am getting the following warning:

```
Mar 19, 2012 4:57:04 PM org.icefaces.impl.event.BridgeSetup isListenerForSource
WARNING: ICEfaces configured for view /xmlhttp/css/rime/css-images/bullet.gif but h:head and h:body components are required
```

please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This just means that you are loading a page that does not have `<h:head>` nor `<h:body>` defined. Do it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

<h:head>
    <title>MyPage</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <!-- put your icefaces stuff in here -->
</h:body>
</html>
```